# Square root to 50 decimal places without importing decimal or math function

Tags: python, square-root

Is it possible to calculate to 50 decimal places without having to use the decimal import? The below prints what I want but I would like to know how to do it without any math or decimal import.

```
def sqrt2(num, P):
    decimal.getcontext().prec = P + len(str(num)) + 2
    x = decimal.Decimal(num)
    y = decimal.Decimal(1)
    e = decimal.Decimal(10) ** decimal.Decimal(-P)
    while (x - y >= e):
        x = (x + y) / 2
        y = num / x

    
print (sqrt2(2, 50))
```

I also tried:

```
    x=n
    y=1.000000 
    e=0.000001 
    while x-y > e:
        x=(x+y)/2
        y=n/x
    print (x)

n = 2
squareRoot(n)

s = squareRoot(n)
a = format(s, ".2f")
print (s)
```

But got the error message `"unsupported format string passed to NoneType"`

Comment: What is wrong with importing math or decimal?

Comment: Nothing. They both work well but I wanted to find out if it was possible to print out 50 decimal places without using it as the default output is much shorter.  Another way to put it, can I amend the default to make it as long as I want.  I tried the format function but it didnt seem to work.

Comment: Your `squareRoot` function doesn't return anything, so `s` is `None`, which causes `format` to raise an error.

Comment: Please update your question as to what you actually want to know.

Comment: Double precision numbers have 53 bits (16 digits) of precision which is what Python [normal floating-point uses](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).  Thus, you can't get 50 digits of accuracy with just the normal Python floats (i.e. need Decimal or some other library).

Comment: What's the type of `num`? If it's an integer, then you can easily use integer arithmetic to compute an integer square root. By scaling by an appropriate power of 10 up front, you can get as many decimal places as you like. For example, `math.isqrt(2*100**50)` gives you the first 50 places after the decimal point of the square root of 2. That uses `math`, but it's easy to write your own `isqrt` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should mention is that your `sqrt` function does not return any value. So None is returned. Just add the line

```
return(x)
```

to the end of function definition and better remove line `print(x)` too to make your function return the value instead of printing it.

But the question is deeper. First of all, mention, that `float` length in python 3 (built-in) is only approx. 16 decimal digits after point. So we can`t calculate more precisely. There are modules which can allow you doing that: numpy supports float128 (approx. 32 decimal digits), if that's not enough - have a look at Decimal or mpmath. Both are well-documented and support higher precision. There's no built-in method.

An article about high-precision calculations in python and reasons why they are required:
https://habr.com/ru/post/305276/